# Using optim to estimate parameters from multiple time series with different constants

Tags: r, ode

I am trying to estimate model parameters using multiple time series where a constant value differs between the series. For ease of explanation I'll use a logistic growth model as an example.

I've been able to estimate a parameter (r) from multiple time series (N1, and N2) with the same constant value of K.

```r
#Data; needs to be matrix instead of data frame
 dat <- as.matrix(cbind(time=seq(0,166,by=16),
         N1=c(0.020,0.030,0.060,0.100,0.160,0.26,0.360,0.50,0.70,0.800,0.90),
         N2=c(0.015,0.033,0.062,0.106,0.162,0.26,0.306,0.51,0.76,0.821,0.91)))

 #dynamical model to estimate r
 dNdt.model=function(t,x,params){
   N <- x
   with(as.list(c(params)), {
     dN <- r*N*(1-(N/K))
     list(c(dN))
   })
 }

 #sse objective function
 sse.dNdt=function(dNparams, data, Kfix=1){
   t <- data[,1]
   N <- data[,-1]
   N0 <- data[1,-1] 
   K <- Kfix
   r0 <- dNparams
   out <- as.data.frame(ode(y=N0, times=t, func=dNdt.model, parms=c(r=r0, K=K)))
   sse <- sum((out[2]-N)^2) + sum((out[3]-N)^2) #SSE needs to be sum of all trajectories
 }

 #run optim
 dNparams <- c(.3) #initial value of r
 optim(dNparams, sse.dNdt, data=dat) #estimate r based on N1 and N2 trajectories
```

Which returns the expected output:

$par
[1] 0.0637207

$value
[1] 4.279062

$counts
function gradient 
      32       NA

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

How do I convert this code to take a different value of K for each time series? Converting Kfix to a vector of 2 values returns an error: object 'K' not found.

Comment: Should `sse <- sum((out[2]-K)^2) + sum((out[3]-N)^2) ` read `sse <- sum((out[2]-N)^2) + sum((out[3]-N)^2)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `purrr::map2_dfc` to run the model for each time series and `K` value and returns a data frame where each column corresponds to a time series.

```
# Load package
library(deSolve)

# Data for fitting
dat <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 166, by=16),
                  N1 = c(0.020, 0.030, 0.060, 0.100, 0.160, 
                         0.26, 0.360, 0.50, 0.70, 0.800, 0.90),
                  N2 = c(0.015, 0.033, 0.062, 0.106, 0.162, 
                         0.26, 0.306, 0.51, 0.76, 0.821, 0.91))

# Model
dNdt_model <- function(t, x, params){
  # State variable
  N <- x

  with(as.list(c(params)), {
    # Rate of change
    dN <- r*N*(1-(N/K))

    #Return list
    list(c(dN))
  })
}
```

The code below is the only part that really changed (aside from my compulsive tidying). `purrr::map2_dfc` loops through each initial condition and `K` value and runs the model. The results are bound together into a data frame. Finally, the observations are subtracted from the model results and the sum of the squares calculated.

```
#sse objective function
sse_dNdt <- function(dNparams, data, K){
  # Output times
  t <- data[,1]

  # Time series
  N <- data[,-1]

  # Run for each time series (different initial condition, different K value)
  out <- purrr::map2_dfc(.x = data[1,-1], .y = K, 
                         ~ ode(y = .x, times = t, func = dNdt_model, parms = c(r = dNparams, K = .y))[, 2])

  #SSE needs to be sum of all trajectories
  sum((out - N)^2) 
}
```

But, what does `purrr::map2_dfc` do? As it's name shows, it maps for two variables (`map2`), which are the initial condition and the `K` value, and returns a data frame (`df`) that is produced by binding columns (`c`, as opposed to `r` for rows).

```
# Initial value of r
dNparams <- c(.3)
```

Below, I call `optim` with an array of `K` values.

```
# Run with different K values for time series N1 and N1
optim(dNparams, sse_dNdt, data = dat, K = c(1, 2))
```